# How to hide an implementation when using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, visual-studio-code

If I were using Visual Studio regular and I wanted to program against an interface, I'd put the interface definition in one project and an implementation of the interface in another project, and then my consuming code would only reference the interface definition. At run time, a dependency injector would stitch everything up. This keeps things simple because my consuming code doesn't know about any implementations of the interface.

How would I have a similar degree of encapsulation when using Visual Studio Code, given that this editor doesn't work with projects?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you creating `csproj` files in VS Code, though I'd recommend using VS for that.

Comment: But is VS Code going to compile them and keep track of project dependencies?

Comment: VS doesn't compile anything, it's a text editor.

Comment: So I don't think projects are going to be a convenient solution to my problem here.

Comment: Well I don't know what your problem is, but I'd say stick with VS (the IDE)

Comment: The problem is to get the encapsulation of projects without using projects.

Comment: If it were possible to get the encapsulation of projects without using projects, then people wouldn't be using projects as much as they do.

Comment: Both .Net framework and .Net core can work on projects. Both use .csproj files for projects and .sln files for solutions. So, it seems like what you want is built into both sdk's.

Comment: You can still _program to interfaces_ and reap the benefits of that, even though you place interface and implementation in the same project. Benefit is loose coupling, which leads to increased testability, extendability and maintainability.

Comment: @alexriedl Yes, except VS Core doesn't manage projects.